# How do I use private functions/variables in the Javascript module pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I'm reading [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) article about the Javascript Module Pattern and came across a snippet which claims you can preserve private variables/functions across module files and access them from each other:

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    var _private = my._private = my._private || {},
        _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function () {
            delete my._private;
            delete my._seal;
            delete my._unseal;
        },
        _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function () {
            my._private = _private;
            my._seal = _seal;
            my._unseal = _unseal;
        };

        // permanent access to _private, _seal, and _unseal

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

I'm a little confused as to how I go about implementing this, but I think most of that confusion is from not understanding quite how this works; how does it enable other scripts already loaded to utilize those internal values? And how do I add functions and variables within this 'private' space?

My end goal is to provide a sort of 'abstract' function variable that must be overridden in sub-modules, but still needs referenced in the base module's file. Admittedly I haven't played with this much but that's mostly because I'm trying to wrap my head around how the actual implementation works.

I was thinking of something like the following but it doesn't seem to work as it can't access the internal functions:

```
    // Preserve state of private variables/functions across modules
    var _private = my._private = my._private || {},
        _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function () {
            delete my._private;
            delete my._seal;
            delete my._unseal;
        },
        _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function () {
            my._private = _private;
            my._seal = _seal;
            my._unseal = _unseal;
        };

    my._private._unseal();

    my._private.bindEvents = function () {
        alert("This function should be re-declared in your sub-module.");
    };

    my._private._seal();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> My end goal is to provide a sort of 'abstract' function variable that
>   must be overridden in sub-modules, but still needs referenced in the
>   base module's file. Admittedly I haven't played with this much but
>   that's mostly because I'm trying to wrap my head around how the actual
>   implementation works.

First of all, move forward. JavaScript isn't a traditional object-oriented programming language.

In JavaScript, if you want to *do something if it's defined*, you would do this:

```
// Look at entire prototype chain for a function
if("doStuff" in obj) {
     obj.doStuff();
}

// Or just check if the own object has the whole function
if(obj.hasOwnProperty("doStuff")) {
     obj.doStuff();
}
```

As of the thing of private or any visibility on JavaScript, everything you may find around the net is just a *trick* because currently JavaScript has no access modifiers.

Anyway, your sample adds `_seal` and `_private` properties to `my` which usually is called `exports`, and defines that adding properties to the object set to these top-level properties are private or sealed by convention. So, yes, it's just a convention: don't access such properties that are part of the object set to `_private` from outside of the module...

BTW, my two cents here is that you should avoid this and use JavaScript *as is* and deal with the fact that there're no access modifiers.

In the mean time, ECMA-Script 2015 and above have defined a new way to declare properties on which the property name are unique identifiers known as [*symbols*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). If you don't own the symbol, you can't access the whole property:

```
let sampleSymbol = Symbol("sample symbol");
let sampleSymbol2 = Symbol("sample symbol 2");

var obj = {
    // Defines the property with a symbol during object
    // declaration
    [sampleSymbol]: "hello world"
};

// Defines the property using regular property declaration syntax
// once the object has been already built
obj[sampleSymbol2] = "goodbye!";
```

Now export this object using *module pattern* and other modules won't be able to access the whole property in an easy way, which in turn works well to simulate property access *private* modifier.

The worst part is you can still get a given object symbols using `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` function, but symbols aren't part of an iterator like `Array.prototype.forEach(...)`, `for..in`, `Object.keys(...)`, or `for..of`, so you should go for it.